# run Multiple Jssor Caption at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jssor

i have a jssor slider, and i want to animate the first slide, i want two images to come from the two sides and integrate in the center.

i used a div for each image, and give a caption for each div, it works well, but the second one start moving after the fist one reach the center ( finish transforming ). i want them to move at the same time.
how can i do that ?

this the option in javascript file :

```
var options = {
            $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
            $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to declare and set value on attribute **d** with negative number representing the duration of your first image ?
It representing the delay, in millisecond, to play the caption on the UIelement.
For example,

```
<img u="caption" t="T" du="1000" t2="NO" src="IMAGE_FILE_URI_1" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 50px; left: 100px;" />
<img u="caption" t="T" d="-1000" du="1000" t2="NO" src="IMAGE_FILE_URI_2" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 100px; left: 100px;" />
```